# Calculating covariance for continuous distributions in R

Tags: r, probability, distribution, stat, probability-density

I know the covariance for discrete distributions can be calculated using the cov and cov.wt functions in R. For example the covariance for the below distribution can be solved like this,

[image]

```
weight <- c(.2,.05,.1,.15,.2,.3)

x <- c(100,250,100,250,100,250)

y <- c(0,0,100,100,200,200)

xy <- cbind (x,y)

cov.wt(xy, wt=weight,method='ML')

Result: 1875
```

Can the covariance for continuous distributions be calculated in a similar way? For instance this question,

[image]

The answer is 1.5625 if you do it manually, but how can this be done using R (base R would be preferred). Thanks!